# Exception handling to Implement Socket timeout using TPL FromAsync

Tags: c#, exception, .net-4.0, task-parallel-library

I am working on an application where a connection attempt timeout should be configurable.

If you take a look at the code below, you will realize that I am trying to do: wait for 20 milliseconds (it is hardcoded by the moment) and, if the connection could be established then invoke the onConnected callback action with true; otherwise with false (if timeout happend, for example)

```
internal void Connect(Action<bool> onConnected)
{
    Func<AsyncCallback, object, IAsyncResult> beginConnect =
        (callback, s) =>
            {
                var asyncResult = _socket.BeginConnect(Endpoint, callback, s);
                var success = asyncResult.AsyncWaitHandle.WaitOne(20, true);
                if(!success) throw new TimeoutException("Connection timeout");
                return asyncResult;
            };

    var task = Task.Factory.FromAsync(beginConnect, _socket.EndConnect, this);
    task.ContinueWith(t => onConnected(true), TaskContinuationOptions.NotOnFaulted)
        .ContinueWith(t => onConnected(false), TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnFaulted);
    task.ContinueWith(t => onConnected(false), TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnFaulted);
}
```

The problem is the callback is never invoked because of the timeout exception in the beginConnect function. I think I could, in the Connect method caller, wrap the call with a tyr-catch statement but it can have several callers and do that in every single caller looks wrong.

How can I achieve what I want to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a way to achieve what I was looking for:

```
internal void Connect(Action<bool> onConnected)
{
    Func<AsyncCallback, object, IAsyncResult> beginConnect =
        (callback, s) => 
            {
                var asyncResult = _socket.BeginConnect(Endpoint, callback, s);
                var success = asyncResult.AsyncWaitHandle.WaitOne(20, true);
                if(!success)
                {
                    onConnected(false);
                    return default(IAsyncResult);
                }
                return asyncResult;
            };

    var task = Task.Factory.FromAsync(beginConnect, _socket.EndConnect, this);
    task.ContinueWith(t => onConnected(true), TaskContinuationOptions.NotOnFaulted)
        .ContinueWith(t => onConnected(false), TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnFaulted);
    task.ContinueWith(t => onConnected(false), TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnFaulted);
}
```

The point is that after 20ms, if not connected yet, it calls the callback with false and return a default IAsyncResult.

Comment: Why `default(ISyncResult)` instead of `null`?

Comment: Because I like it and some times I don´t have to know if it is a value or reference type. Do you think there is a good reason to replace it by null, @Matt?

Comment: it just made it read strange since it will always evaluate to `null` in this case.  I (personally) would only use it when it could actually evaluate to something different (i.e. when generics are involved)